# Declare struct type, insert values into array of the type, and print out array

Tags: c

In this program, I would like to define a struct called person, and an insert function for inserting an element into unused space in the array which is declared as type person. Lastly, I would like to print out the results as standard output. Could anyone give me a hint for correct anything which is wrong? Cheers

Error:

```
arrays.c:16:22: error: expected ')' before '[' token
arrays.c: In function 'main':
arrays.c:34:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'insert'
arrays.c:41:5: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **'
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array */
char *names[7]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet"};
int ages[7]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};


/* declare your struct for a person here */
typedef struct{
  char name;
  int ages; 
}  person;

static void insert (p[], char *name, int ages) {

  static int nextfreeplace = 0;
  /* put name and age into the next free place in the array parameter here */
  person p[0] = {&name, age};

  /* modify nextfreeplace here */
  nextfreeplace++;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  /* declare the people array here */
   person p[7];

   //insert the members and age into the unusage array. 
  for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    insert (p[i], &names[i], ages[i]);
    p[i]= p[i+1];

  }

  /* print the people array here*/
  for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("%s is %d years old\n", &names[i], ages[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The location of the `nextfreeplace` variable is dubious. You will need to know how many rows are in the array (which is what the variable records) for looping over the data, etc., and for deleting them.  You probably need to make that more visible for anything more than the current problem.  Also, you would have no way of emptying the array; nor could you have two separate arrays of people managed by the function.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is your struct person. You're declaring name as a *char* while it should be a **char* (pointer)** or a **char[] (array)**.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char *name; //or char name[100];
    int age;
}
person;
```

Next, your **insert**  **function** has incorrect arguments. You don't want an array of persons (you could do it but this is simpler), you want a **pointer to a person struct** so you can edit it.

```
static void insert(person *p, char *name, int age)
{
    p->name = name;
    p->age = age;
}
```

Finally, this is how you would populate your array and print it out:

```
int main()
{
    //names and ages...

    person people[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        insert(&people[i], names[i], ages[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("name: %s, age: %i\n", people[i].name, people[i].age);
    }
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/dzGWId.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the parameter `p`.

```
static void insert (p[], char *name, int ages)
```

You've forgotten its type (`person`). Then you redeclare it; the following instruction is invalid:

```
person p[0] = {&name, age};
```

In the function call, you don't use an array, but a case of an array. So your function should be:

```
typedef struct
{
  char *name;
  int ages;
} person;

static void
insert (person *p, char *s, int n)
{
  p->name = s;
  p->ages = n;
}
```

And the call:

```
insert (&p[i], names[i], ages[i]);
```